# Projection onto closed subspace with finite codimension

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces

> Let $X$ be a $\mathbb K \in \{\mathbb R, \mathbb C\}$ Banach space and $U \le X$ closed with finite codimension. Show that there exists a continuous projection onto $U$.

So finite codimension means $dim(X/U)=n<\infty$. Hence I can find a basis $\{x_1+U,...,x_n+U\}$. Now consider $V:= span\{x_1,...,x_n\} \le X$. It can be shown that there is a continous projection $P$ onto $V$. And then $1-P$ should project onto $U$, right? Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

There exists $e_1,..,e_n$ such that $U\oplus Vect(e_1,...,e_n)=X$. Let $U_i=U+Vect(e_1,..,\hat {e_i},..,e_n)$, it is a closed subset of codimension $1$, the form $f_i$ defined by $f_{\mid U_i}=0, f(e_i)=1$ is continuous.

Denote $p:X\rightarrow X$ defined by $p(x)=x-\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}f_i(x)e_i$, show that $p$ is a projection onto $U$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What does $\hat e_i$ denote? Where do we use that $U_i$ is closed?

Comment: Also curious about what does ̂_i denote?

Answer (score 0):

By induction on the co-dimension of $U.$

(I). If $U$ is of co-dimension $1$ let $0\ne x_1\in X$ \ $U.$ For $k\in \Bbb K$ and $y\in U$ let $P(kx_1+y)=y.$

Then $P$ is well-defined because if $kx_1+y=k'x_1+y'$ with $k,k'\in \Bbb K$ and $y,y'\in U$ then $(k-k')x=y'-y\in U\implies k-k'=0 \implies y'-y=0.$

If a sequence $(k_nx_1+y_n)_n$ converges, its limit is $kx_1+y$ for some $k\in \Bbb K$ and some $y\in U$ (because $\{kx_1:k\in \Bbb K\}+U=X$).

And $|k_n-k|\cdot \inf_{z\in U}\|x_1-z\|\leq \|(k_n-k)x_1+(y_n-y)\|\to 0,$ so $k_n\to k$ (because $\inf_{z\in U}\|x_1-z\|>0$  because $x_1\not \in U=\bar U$).

Hence  $\|y_n-y\|\leq \|(k_n-k)x_1+(y_n-y)\|+\|-(k_n-k)x_1\|\to 0$ implies $y_n\to y.$ So $(P(k_nx_1+y_n))_n=(y_n)_n$ converges to $y=P(kx_1+y).$

So $P$ is continuous. Obviously $P$ is linear and $P|_U=id_U$, and $P(P(x))=P(x)$ for all $x\in X.$

(II). If $U$ is of co-dimension $n>1,$ suppose the result holds for any closed linear subspace of co-dimension $n-1.$ Let $\{x_1,...,x_n\}\subset X$ be a vector-space basis for $V$ such that $U+V=X.$ Let $V'$ be the vector space  generated by $\{x_2,...,x_n\}.$ Then $U+V'$ is a closed vector subspace of $X$  (because $U=\bar U$ and $V'$ is finite-dimensional) and $U+V'$ is of co-dimension $1$ in $X$. So by (I) there is a continuous projection $P'$ from  $X$ onto $U+V'.$

Now $U +V'$ is a Banach space  and $U$ is a closed linear subspace  of co-dimension $n-1$ in the space $U+V'.$ By the inductive supposition there is a continuous projection $P''$ from the Banach space $U+V'$ onto $U,$ so let $P=P''P'.$

Comment: As one who nitpicks, I could criticize my own answer for not covering the case $n=0.$